# Display 20 curves in the same grafana panel 1 curve x user

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I am using InfluxDB and grafana. I have a data for 20 users.

Here is the query I use to display a single user:

```
SELECT delta  FROM "measures" WHERE user_id='23545296664228'
```

What I want is a panel in Grafana when I can display all 20 series ?

Ideally, it would be great to be able to display/hide series to focus on a specific one.

The goal, here, is to see if there is a specific user that behaves differently from others, and be able to visually identify him

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `user_id` is tag in `measures` measurement you need to use `group by` in query like in this example:

```
SELECT delta  FROM "measures"  WHERE time > now() - 1d GROUP BY time(1h),user_id
```